# using window.location.replace render page without calling the .ready function windows phone 7 phonegap project

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-7, cordova

Using Cordova 2.4.0 - Windows Phone 7

I tired to navigate from index.html to another html page,
the html page rendered successfully and the console said that

> GapBrowser_Navigated :: /app/www/ViewMokhalfaDetails.html

such that ViewMokhalfaDetails.html is the target page But non of scripts has been executed 
althouth i have included the js file at the header of ViewMokhalfaDetails.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ViewMokhalfaDetails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in ViewMokhalfaDetails.js file I wrote this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {console.log("Hello from .ready function")} );
```

I have no idea why the code inside the .ready didn't executed successfully.

**Update 1**
I've added a button and bind onclick event to a function in located in the js file 
it does the same functionality of .ready function
so the problem is in the .ready() function

**Update 2**
The localStorage["Key entered from 1st page"] is cleared in the destination page after using window.location.replace.

Comment: Is the javascript file ViewMokhalfaDetails.js located in Scripts folder? And do check the capitalisation of the 'S' in Scripts.

Comment: yes everything is in the correct place, other pages are working correctly I don't know why this page especially has the error, btw I've tried to move the .ready code in the <script></script> tag inside the HTML itself but the same problem occurs!!

Comment: Can you try running this page independently in a browser(maybe chrome) and check the console for any errors.

Comment: Tested and no errors is fired, 
btw I've tested the page cross browsers IE, Chrome and FireFox

Answer (score 0):

It is because the way you are transitioning to the other html page. If its on a click of a button try adding to the button tag or anchor tag the following:

```
rel="external"
```

if you are going to the other page programmatically try putting your scripts at the end of the page after closing the body tag like this:

```
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {console.log("Hello from .ready function")} );
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: try putting the jquery script before the cordova script

Comment: I did ur suggestion in all pages but still .ready not firing in the desired page. :'(